# MySQL Trigger modify col before insert

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to modify col before record is inserted inside! I have table for transactions and for every new transaction i want to set `0.5%` commission.

Problem with is: he all time insert `0` in `amount` col. But i want current `current value x 0.50%`

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `viptest`.`testing`;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    /*[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]*/
    TRIGGER `viptest`.`commission_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT
    ON `viptest`.`transaction_history`
    FOR EACH ROW        
    BEGIN
       SET NEW.amount = NEW.amount % 0.50';
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: The correct expression for adding a 0.5% commission is `NEW.amount * 1.005` but you should probably not be doing this by modifying the input data with a trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `viptest`.`testing`;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
/*[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]*/
TRIGGER `viptest`.`commission_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT
ON `viptest`.`transaction_history`
FOR EACH ROW        
BEGIN

   -- If you just want to modify current row, this line should work
   SET NEW.amount = NEW.amount * 0.5 / 100;

   -- If you want to process this commission into another table, you can use this line
   insert into db_name.table_name (col1, col2, col3)
   select (val1, NEW.amount * 0.5 / 100, val3);

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```